# iOS 6 - Force portrait mode only not working

Tags: iphone, ios6, orientation, landscape, portrait

I made an app which needs to be only in portrait orientation.

I set up portrait in the Plist file, in the Project Infos, I tried everything, but my app still changes orientation.
My app is using an *ShSideBarController* in Appdelegate and then 4 views, which are tableviewcontroller.

Comment: Did you also change screen orientations in Target -> Summary?

Answer (score 1):

Try to put this code in your viewcontrollers:

```
//for iOS6   
 -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
    {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
      }


    -(BOOL) shouldAutorotate
    {
        return YES;
    }
```